# ArgumentError invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

## What I want to solve

The following error occurs when downloading that file, compressed into a single zip file.

`invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`.

For this error, I have to remove illegal characters as UTF-8 from the string, so I used encode method to convert from UTF-8 to UTF-8, but the string I want to display is not displayed. It looks like the image.

`file_name.encode!("UTF-8", "UTF-8", invalid: :replace)`

[image]

Is there any solution to this problem?

I would be glad to know.

## source code

```
        Zip::File.open_buffer(obj) do |zip|

          zip.each do |entry|
            ext = File.extname(entry.name)
            file_name = File.basename(entry.name)

            # file_name.encode!("UTF-8", "UTF-8", invalid: :replace)

            next if ext.blank? || file_name.count(".") > 1

            dir = File.join(dir_name, File.dirname(entry.name))

            FileUtils.mkpath(dir.to_s)      

            zip.extract(entry, dir + ".txt" || ".jpg" || ".csv") {true}

            file_name.force_encoding("UTF-8")
            new_file_name = "#{dir_name}/#{file_name}"

            new_file_name.force_encoding("UTF-8")
            File.rename(dir + ".txt" || ".jpg" || ".csv", new_file_name)

            @input_dir << new_file_name
          end
        end
        
        Zip::OutputStream.open(zip_file.path) do |zip_data|
          @input_dir.each do |file|
          zip_data.put_next_entry(file)
          zip_data.write(File.read(file.to_s))
          end
        end
```

## environment

mac OS Catarina 10.15.7
ruby "2.6.3"

Comment: Can you show `file_name.codepoints` along with the expected result?

Comment: @Stefan This is the file_name.codepoints. 
[87, 78, 83, 95, 85, 80, 65533, 112, 65533, 102, 65533, 91, 65533, 94, 46, 116, 120, 116]
However, to show this code point, we revived the code in (1). Is this correct?
 (1)file_name.encode!("UTF-8", "UTF-8", invalid: :replace)

Comment: `65533` is the _replacement character_, i.e. �. It seems like you ran the code after the conversion? Sorry for not being clear. Please run `entry.name.codepoints` and also `entry.name.encoding` and post their output.

Comment: @Stefan entry.name.codepoints could not be displayed with the following error. `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`.

Just tried outputting file_name.codepoints with the expected file name of the same name.
[87, 78, 83, 95, 85, 80, 29992, 12486, 12441, 12540, 12479, 46, 116, 120, 116]

entry.name.encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: Try `entry.name.bytes` then.

Comment: @Stefan This is the entry.name.bytes: `[111, 117, 116, 112, 117, 116, 50, 48, 50, 48, 49, 50, 48, 55, 95, 49, 52, 49, 54, 48, 50, 47, 87, 78, 83, 95, 85, 80, 151, 112, 131, 102, 129, 91, 131, 94, 46, 116, 120, 116]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225749/discussion-between-taizo-and-stefan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get these errors because the Zip gem assumes the filenames to be encoded in UTF-8 but they are actually in a different encoding.

To fix the error, you first have to find the correct encoding. Let's re-create the string from its bytes:

```
bytes = [111, 117, 116, 112, 117, 116, 50, 48, 50, 48, 49,
         50, 48, 55, 95, 49, 52, 49, 54, 48, 50, 47, 87,
         78, 83, 95, 85, 80, 151, 112, 131, 102, 129, 91,
         131, 94, 46, 116, 120, 116]

string = bytes.pack('c*')
#=> "output20201207_141602/WNS_UP\x97p\x83f\x81[\x83^.txt"
```

We can now traverse the [`Encoding.list`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Encoding.html) and [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Array.html#select-method) those that return the [expected result](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/51123682#51123682):

```
Encoding.list.select do |enc|
  s = string.encode('UTF-8', enc) rescue next
  s.end_with?('WNS_UP用データ.txt')
end
#=> [
#     #<Encoding:Windows-31J>,
#     #<Encoding:Shift_JIS>,
#     #<Encoding:SJIS-DoCoMo>,
#     #<Encoding:SJIS-KDDI>,
#     #<Encoding:SJIS-SoftBank>
#   ]
```

All of the above encodings result in the correct output.

Back to your code, you could use:

```
path = entry.name.encode('UTF-8', 'Windows-31J')
#=> "output20201207_141602/WNS_UP用データ.txt"

ext = File.extname(path)
#=> ".txt"

file_name = File.basename(path)
#=> "WNS_UP用データ.txt"
```

The Zip gem also has an option to set an explicit encoding for [non-ASCII file names](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip#non-ascii-names). You might want to give it a try by setting `Zip.force_entry_names_encoding = 'Windows-31J'` (haven't tried it)

Comment: I was impressed. This solution solved the problem. It also worked this way. I had never imagined this way `Zip.force_entry_names_encoding = 'Windows-31J'`. I'm a newbie, so I'll post more questions. I really appreciate your help in resolving the problem.

Comment: @taizo you’re welcome. If this was helpful and solved your problem, you might want to upvote it and tick the green checkmark.